# Numbering stanzas instead of lines with verse package

Tags: verse

I'd like to reproduce the way stanzas (8-line stanzas) are numbered in this image bellow.

[image: 1]

Please, don't mind reproducing its details, italics, adornments, and capital letter etc. I am only looking for a way to **automatically** number stanzas, at the right margin (as in the picture) or at the left margin, it doesn't matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It does add numbers to stanzas, but not automatically, as it needs the `\flagverseR` function at each `begin{verse}` of stanza, which is fine for a poem, say, of 2 stanzas; for poems of a thousand stanzas, it'd be tiresome.

Comment: That can be solved by appending the counter increase and display to the environment definition, i.e., `\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{altverse}{\upverse\flagverseR{\thevscntr}}`.

Comment: You dislike the `\flagverse` function. How do you suggest indicating the contents of a stanza with respect to the previous/following stanzas? User input to help improve a package is always useful.